# Re-format Custom Value as Text (leading zeros)

Tags: excel, vba

I face an issue with the following user input and leading zeros.
The design sheet foresees that the entered value will be formatted as text, but if the user copy pastes values it has the custom format in it.

Goal:
The desired visible value should be: 0005
The desired input should be: 0005

edit: the lengths can vary. sometimes 0005 but also sometimes 00000005 or only 05.

Now:
The desired visible value is: 0005
The desired input is: 5

[image]

I cannot prevent copy paste of values, but I want to make sure the values will be formatted as text, so that further processing will use "0005" instead of "5".

I tried this one, but it will format the cell as text and shows the value "5" afterwards.
"LobjAccount" -> Listobject
Actually the whole column should be formatted as text because it has hundreds of numbers with leading zeros.

```
Sub testvalue()
    Call declareVariables
    LObjAccounts.DataBodyRange.Cells(2, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
End Sub
```

Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Comment: While you format the column as text you must input `0005` not only 5.

Comment: Try `.NumberFormat = "00000"` This way if you input `5` in the cell, it will change to `0005`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Values are dynamic, not fixed to 4 digits

Comment: @Mech not working.

Comment: So how many leading 0's do you want?

Comment: Those numbers have no fixed lengths. they can vary form use case to use case.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase. User enters these 3 numbers in say cells `A1:A3`. 5, 203 and 14500. What should these numbers change to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223266/discussion-between-smartini-and-siddharth-rout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if they input "5" then thats OK. if they input "0004" (with custom format) then "0004" should be used, eventhough "4" is the value in excel
> basically: VBA must use the value "shown" to the user, and not the one being in the "backend"

In such a case you have 2 option.

Use `Cell.Text` to work with what is shown. There is a drawback with this method. Say if the cell has `000004` and the cell's column width is reduced so that you only see `###`. In such a case `Cell.Text` will give you `###`

The other option would be to use `Format` as shown below

```
Debug.Print Format(SomeCell.Value2, SomeCell.NumberFormat)
```

> so the value in excel is "6", but it is formatted and displayed as "0006"
> i need VBA to input "0006" (hard" in the cell
> instead of "6" being already there

In such a case you can combin the above with `'` and use this

```
SomeCell.Value = "'" & Format(SomeCell.Value2, SomeCell.NumberFormat)
```

For example, let's say `6` is in cell `A1` which has a format `0006` then you can write it as

```
Range(A1").Value = "'" & Format(Range(A1").Value2, Range(A1").NumberFormat)
```